# Golang tour Switch evaluation order: time.Now().Weekday() + 2 yields runtime error: index out of range

Tags: go, time

I am learning Golang, was going through the tour where I found a tutorial on **Switch evaluation order**. I modified it a bit (e.g. Saturday to Sunday), just to play around. It printed *Too far away.* even for Sunday. So, I modified the code to look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    day := time.Monday

    fmt.Printf("When's %v?\n", day)
    today := time.Now().Weekday()

    switch day {
    case today + 0:
        fmt.Println("Today.")
    case today + 1:
        fmt.Println("Tomorrow.", today + 1)
    case today + 2:
        fmt.Println("In two days.", today + 2)
    default:
        fmt.Println("Too far away.", today + 2)
    }
}
```

Now, it gives me the output:

```
When's Monday?
Too far away. %!v(PANIC=runtime error: index out of range)
```

What can I do to MOD the index, instead of adding it beyond array? Seems to me like some kind of operator overloading. Shouldn't it do MOD, on add operation, by default in case of days, at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an implementation detail.

In this line

```
fmt.Println("In two days.", today + 2)
```

`today` is of type [`time.Weekday`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday) which has `int` as its underlying type, `2` is an untyped integer constant, which will be converted to `time.Weekday` and the addition will be carried out.

The implementation of [`fmt.Println()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Println) will check if values passed to it implement [`fmt.Stringer`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer), and because `time.Weekday` does, its [`String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Weekday.String) method will be called whose implementation is:

```
// String returns the English name of the day ("Sunday", "Monday", ...).
func (d Weekday) String() string { return days[d] }
```

Where `days` is an array of 7 elements:

```
var days = [...]string{
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  }
```

There is no range check in `Weekday.String()` because `time.Saturday + 2` for example is not a weekday. `Weekday.String()` only guarantees to work properly for the constants defined in the `time` package:

```
type Weekday int

const (
    Sunday Weekday = iota
    Monday
    Tuesday
    Wednesday
    Thursday
    Friday
    Saturday
)
```

If you want to make it work, you have to use the remainder after dividing by 7, like this:

```
switch day {
case (today + 0) % 7:
    fmt.Println("Today.")
case (today + 1) % 7:
    fmt.Println("Tomorrow.", (today+1)%7)
case (today + 2) % 7:
    fmt.Println("In two days.", (today+2)%7)
default:
    fmt.Println("Too far away.", (today+2)%7)
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is called the [modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Comment: That sample there caught me off guard. I thought, for a sec, that `(today+1)%7` would give me an integer, but the modulus operator is overloaded too... It's spinning my head. Concentrating on *switch* for now.

Comment: @icza does `d` in here `func (d Weekday) String() string { return days[d] }` is an `int`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya It's a numerical value of type `time.Weekday`.